# In a CSS print stylesheet, can I display an absolute URL when the href in the HTML is relative?

Tags: css

I have a print stylesheet which adds a URL after links. Something like this:

```
@media print {
  a:after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ") ";
  }
}
```

This results in a link like this.

```
this is an <a href='/foo.html'>example</a> of some HTML'
```

being displayed as:

```
this is an example ("/foo.html") of some HTML
```

whereas I should like it to be displayed as:

```
this is an example ("http://www.example.com/foo.html") of some HTML
```

Is it possible to read the base url of the site from within CSS?

Comment: No, can't do that with CSS. The `attr()` treat the attribute's value as a `string`.

Answer (score 2):

I would do that within HTML, using PHP or javascript to get the base URL, and put that into a span with a class which is only displayed in the `@media print` version, whereas a link with the relative URL is in another span which is visible on screen but not in the print version.

Comment: At that point you might as well stick to the absolute URLs instead of wasting resources swapping between the two.

Comment: yes, true - but you could do that anyway, no matter which method you think about...

Comment: @BoltClock Your suggestion led me to a solution. Absolute URLs are the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

While it seems impossible to retrieve the base URL from CSS, you could always place it in a CSS variable at the top of the document and then use that to format your links. However, there are three types of links you can write, and the ones we actually call *relative* links would need to know the current page you're on, so this hack won't help you there. Besides, a link could also include `../../parent_accessors` which you wouldn't want to keep in the URL.

```css
html {
  --base-url: "https://stackoverflow.com";
}

a[href*="://"]::after,
a:not([href^="/"])::after
{
  content: " (" attr(href) ")";
}

a[href^="/"]:not([href*="://"])::after {
  content: " (" var(--base-url) attr(href) ")";
}
```

```html
This is a <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css">link with full path</a>.<br>
This is an <a href="/questions/tagged/css">absolute link</a>.<br>
This is a <a href="sample.html">relative link</a>.
```

Okay, due to how snippets work here, those links don't actually point to stackoverflow, but you get the idea. All in all, not a very interesting approach. This should be done using server-side code instead of CSS.